# Sending a value from Arduino-GSM device to Django Python application

Tags: python, django, arduino, gps, gsm

So I'm looking into something new, I have an Arduino GPS tracker created, and it can send SMS messages with the location it is in. **It automatically does that.**

I want to light things up a bit, and get the location on a web server. So I prepared a simple django application with only one page: [Click Here](https://evening-harbor-27728.herokuapp.com/create/). This is simply a form that will take the location and store it in my database.

Here is the code of the form (form is already passed in from a django view):

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Add">
```

My question is, what is the arduino code that should be added so that once the arduino captures the location, it passes that location value to the django page I mentioned up there and submits it to the database automatically...
I guess it would be using some HTTP request from the Arduino side? I don't know to be honest, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need a form. just use a view and process the `POST` data. (and maybe add some kind of authentication - like a token)

Comment: what's the arduino code? I honestly have no idea

Comment: see example here (POST): http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient